# performFetchWithCompletionHandler não sendo chamado em produção

Tags: ios, swift, parse, apple-push-notification

Estou implementando um app em Swift 2 que faz requisições à um feed xml de tempos em tempos, e dispara uma notificação local. Para tal, estou usando o método `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` no AppDelegate. Localmente, usando meu aparelho, o método é chamado normalmente. Mas já em produção, testando via Testflight, ele nunca é chamado... Eu preciso implementar algo para que ele dispare em produção? O que acontece nesse caso que meus beta testers não recebem notificações automáticas?

PS: estou usando Parse.com, e quando mando notificações manuais, eles recebem

Comment: As requisições de tempos em tempos, seria em torno de quanto tempo? O app está em estado terminado? Se possível coloque o código em que você realiza estas questões

Comment: @Gian, o tempo seria o mínimo possível... Agradeço muito pela ajuda, mas como precisava de algo mais rápido, encontrei uma maneira de resolver esse problema usando Push Notifications com o Parse.com mesmo... Vou postar o código explicando como fiz, pra deixar de informação futura :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema foi contornado, utilizando agora Push Notifications ao invés de Local Notifications. O próprio parse.com oferece um recurso chamado Cloud Code, onde é possível escrever uma task para ler o feed de tempos em tempos e disparar push notifications. Segue o código comentado abaixo:

Lembrando que o código é feito em Javascript, referenciando as bibliotecas [XMLReader](https://github.com/SamDecrock/node-xmlreader) e [SAX](https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js)

```
var xmlreader = require('cloud/xmlreader.js');

var url = "http://www.zelda.com.br/rss.xml";

function SavePost(title, link){
    var PostClass = Parse.Object.extend("Post");
    var post = new PostClass();
    post.set("title", title);
    post.set("link", link);
    post.save();
}

function SendPush(title, link){
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    Parse.Push.send({
        where: query,
        data: {
            url: link,
            alert: title,
            sound: "default"
        }
        }, {
            success: function() {
                SavePost(title, link);
            },
            error: function(error) {
            console.log("Error sending push: " + error);
        }
    });
}

Parse.Cloud.job("fetchPosts", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: url,
        success: function(httpResponse) {
            var responseText = httpResponse.text;

            xmlreader.read(responseText, function (err, res){
                var newPost = res.rss.channel.item;

                var title = newPost.array[0].title.text();
                var link = newPost.array[0].link.text();

                var PostClass = Parse.Object.extend("Post");
                var query = new Parse.Query(PostClass);
                query.equalTo("link", link);
                query.find({
                    success: function(results) {
                        if (results.length == 0){
                            SendPush(title, link);
                        } else {
                            response.error("Post already pushed");
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        },
        error: function(httpResponse) {
            console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
            response.error("Error fetching posts from feed");
        }
    });
});
```